# Countdown Timer Location Specific?

Tags: javascript, html

i've added a JS countdown timer to my website but just realized that it doesn't reference a user's geographical location...

so, for example, if the event is at 3pm sunday pt, the timer will reflect the same for east coast time, 3pm, instead of 6pm... is there a way that to make the timer adjust to location?

here's the code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {

        //custom 'this' selector
        thisEl = $(this);

        //array of custom settings
        var settings = { 
            'date': null,
            'format': null
        };

        //append the settings array to options
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        //main countdown function
        function countdown_proc() {

            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

            if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed

            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed

            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed

            //conditional Ss
            if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
            if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
            if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
            if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

            //logic for the two_digits ON setting
            if(settings['format'] == "on") {
                days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
                hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
                minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
            }

            //update the countdown's html values.
            if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } else { 
                alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
                clearInterval(interval); 
            }
        }

        //run the function
        countdown_proc();

        //loop the function
        interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);

    }
}) (jQuery);
```

**EDIT:**

ok, just now noticed the html code you also provided....

here's my setup right now:

html -

```
<!-- countdown start -->
<div id="countdown-wrapper">
<ul id="countdown">

<!-- days start -->
<li>
<span class="days">00</span>
<p class="timeRefDays">days</p>
</li>

<!-- hours start -->
<li>
<span class="hours">00</span>
<p class="timeRefHours">hours</p>
</li>

<!-- minutes start -->
<li>
<span class="minutes">00</span>
<p class="timeRefMinutes">minutes</p>
</li>

<!-- seconds start -->
<li>
<span class="seconds">00</span>
<p class="timeRefSeconds">seconds</p>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
<!-- end countdown -->
```

here's the script at the bottom of the same page:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
$("#countdown").countdown({
date: "03 February 2019 15:30:00", // countdown target date settings
format: "on"
},

function() {
// callback function
});
});
//]]>
```

i posted the countdown.js file earlier

so how would i tie your code to this?

to be clear, i just want 1 (one) countdown timer to display on my website, set to pt, but i want it to reflect each user's geographical location, i.e. if i'm on the west coast and the countdown shows 1 hour for me, i want it to show 4 hours for east coast users...

thanks again dan, your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you think. The problem is your input. You're not telling it what time zone to work with. Your error example suggests that a "valid date" string is "12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00". That's the problem. When you're working in Javascript in the browser, the system knows what timezone it is in, and whenever you create a timestamp, it converts the time to the preferred programming timezone, GMT. This means that as long as you know what the target timezone is, and you can convert that into GMT as well, you have a solid destination.

Firstly, I'll assume "Tuesday" in this example was meant to be a month (I'll pick December to make it a fun number). Most often, systems use something like the ISO-8601 format (`2012-12-12T09:30:00.000Z`), and I would recommend you either use that or UNIX timestamps (`1355304600000`), but you can even just use the offset-based time: `Dec 12 2012 17:30:00 GMT-0800` if you're going to parse it yourself.

```js
console.info(new Date().toString()); // "Thu Jan 31 2019 17:21:01 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)"
console.info(new Date().toISOString()); // "2019-02-01T00:21:57.468Z" (that's the current time in GMT)
console.info(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()); // 420 (that's minutes between me and GMT)
console.info(Date.now()); // 1548980627330 (unix timestamp)
```

Alternatively you can use something like moment-timezone (https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to deal with the timezones part for you.

**Edit per your question**

There's nothing wrong with the code you've written

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
        var interval; // I added this to keep this variable in scope
        //custom 'this' selector
        var thisEl = $(this); // I added the `var` to keep this variable in scope so you can put more than one on a page.

        //array of custom settings
        var settings = { 
            'date': null,
            'format': null
        };

        //append the settings array to options
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        //main countdown function
        function countdown_proc() {

            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

            if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed

            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed

            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed

            //conditional Ss
            if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
            if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
            if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
            if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

            //logic for the two_digits ON setting
            if(settings['format'] == "on") {
                days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
                hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
                minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
            }

            //update the countdown's html values.
            if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } else { 
                alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
                clearInterval(interval); 
            }
        }

        //run the function
        countdown_proc();

        //loop the function
        interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);

    }
    
    // Eastern Time
    $('#countdown-eastern').countdown({ date: '2020-02-01T22:00:00Z'}, function () {
    console.info('done')
    })
    // Pacific Time
    $('#countdown-pacific').countdown({ date: '2020-02-02T01:00:00Z'}, function () {
    console.info('done')
    })
}) (jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="countdown-eastern">
  <p>Until February 1, 2020, 5PM Eastern Time</p>
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="timeRefDays"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="timeRefHours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="timeRefMinutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
  <span class="timeRefSeconds"></span>
</div>

<div id="countdown-pacific">
  <p>Until February 1, 2020, 5PM Pacific Time</p>
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="timeRefDays"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="timeRefHours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="timeRefMinutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
  <span class="timeRefSeconds"></span>
</div>
```

**To be clear: I added the two `var` declarations at the top of your file, and I only changed the date that went into the .countdown() function, based on the timezone I wanted to be in.**

Comment: thanks very much dan, but what you wrote is above my pay grade... is there a way to edit one )or both) of the two scripts i posted (the first one is the js file that the script references, the second one is the script in my document) so that it will result in what you explained? if so, where would i make the edits, which lines would i edit, or what code would i replace? thank you very much!

Comment: @aeneas1 what is the real value of `settings['date']`? I think that's your only problem. In your example, you put `null`, so I can't tell if that's true or not.

Comment: I guess it's `options.date`

Comment: thanks a ton for your help dan.... i replaced my countdown.js code with the code you provided - they way it's configured on my site, the date is manually set using the code in the html file (that references the countdown.js file), it's currently set to ( date: "03 February 2019 15:30:00",)... should i be good to go or do i need to change anything in the code you provided? thanks again!

Comment: ok, i think i may have figured it out, was confused about not seeing any script for the html file, just the html code and the js script for the js file which you edited a bit... so i went ahead and copied your edited script to my js file, deleted the js script in my html file, changed "#countdown-pacific"  in your edit to "#countdown" to match my html file (so i didn't have re-do all of the css), added my countdown date to the js file, and everything seems to be working fine... does this seem correct? will it now show the right countdown regardless of geo local?

Comment: Nope. The date on your HTML file is bad. It doesn't have a timezone in it, so the browser will think it is the same as the user's timezone. To be clear, as far as I can tell, the ONLY reason your code didn't work originally is that the date in your HTML file doesn't have a timezone. Instead of the date you have listed, use "2019-02-03T15:30:00-07:00", and change "-07:00" to the offset between you and GMT. For me, it's "-07:00", because if you google "mountain time to gmt" it says you have to subtract 7 hours and I'm in Mountain Timezone

Comment: Sorry, your other comment says you're in Pacific, so you want to use "2019-02-03T15:30:00-08:00"

Comment: ok, got it, looks like it's working now, thanks a ton, will mark you solution as the answer (altho i made a huge mess of this thread, hope folks that need the same help can follow it in the future!)!  btw, as i mentioned earlier, i ended up deleting the js script from my html file and am just using the script you provided (i.e. i replaced the script in my countdown.js file with yours), and it works great - so what are the advantages to putting a callback script in the html file? any? thanks again!

Comment: No real reason. Really I wanted a single js file for the plugin and a separate one for the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, you can use the geolocation API for your purposes. You need something like the following:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  /* geolocation is available */
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(/* more code here */)
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available, so for example: */
  setGenericTimer()
}
```

However, they do point out this caveat:

> By default, getCurrentPosition() tries to answer as fast as possible
>   with a low accuracy result. It is useful if you need a quick answer
>   regardless of the accuracy. Devices with a GPS, for example, can take
>   a minute or more to get a GPS fix, so less accurate data (IP location
>   or wifi) may be returned to getCurrentPosition().

Check out the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Comment: i think i spoke too soon... it appears that using "2019-02-03T15:30:00-08:00" displays the correct time on the west coast but subtracts 8 hours from the east coast time, i.e. east coast users are reporting that their clock is 8 hours ahead of users seeing the west coast clock..

Answer (score 0):

thank you hcs...

where would i add this to the script? for example, here's the script in my document that references the script i posted above, would i add the code you posted to this script?

```
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    $("#countdown").countdown({
    date: "03 February 2019 15:30:00", // countdown target date settings
    format: "on"
    },

    function() {
    // callback function
    });
    });
    //]]>
```